# I need some help with a determinants problem

Tags: matrices, determinant

[image]

I've tried to think about it but I don't know how to start

Comment: $a$ $b$ and $c$ are numbers.  Why does it matter if they refer to lengths or angles measurements?

Comment: Actually, I suspect that the book has a typo, so that the question should read
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
a&b&c\\
5&7&8\\
\sin A & \sin B & \sin B
\end{vmatrix}
$$
so that we could use the law of sines.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Well, if they are angles, we know they sum to $\pi$, and if they are sides, they dont have to.

Comment: Like Omnom..., I think the point is to use the law of sines.  Which means the first row probably refers to side lengths and the third row to angle sines.

Answer (score 3):

I would assume that the book has a typo, as I clarify in my comment above.  In particular, I think that the question is really asking about
$$
\begin{vmatrix} a&b&c\\ 5&7&8\\ \sin A & \sin B & \sin C \end{vmatrix}
$$
where $a,b,c$ are the side lengths opposite the angles $A,B,C$. Assuming that this is the case,

**Hint:** note that, by the law of sines, we have
$$
\frac{\sin(C)}{c} = \frac{\sin(B)}{b}
 \implies b\sin(C) = c \sin(B)
$$
Using this inequality and others like it, take a Laplace expansion along the middle row to get the answer (d).

Or, even easier: because $\frac{\sin(A)}{a} = \frac{\sin(B)}{b} = \frac{\sin(C)}{c}$, we may conclude that the third row is a multiple of the first.

Comment: Good work.  I suggest you incorporate your comment into your answer for completeness though.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang good point, done.